# Separating data transformation functionally from model classes

Tags: design-patterns, class-design

I'm developing a tool for automated report generation in C++. For that, I read a couple of CSV and text files and store the data in model classes, which only consist of simple getter and setter methods.

On run-time, I have to transform some of the data from the model classes into another representation, which I then have to feed into another system. Currently, the logic for the transformation of the data is done in the model classes itself. I want to separate the logic for the transformation of the data from the model classes so that future changes to the transformation logic don't affect the model classes.

Where would be the best place for that logic? Is there maybe a design pattern for such a case?

Hint: I don't use the MVC pattern.

Comment: I suspect you're looking for an adapter pattern.

Comment: No: "adapter" is not the right pattern, definitely.

Answer (score 0):

I'd say your application has [at least] two responsibilities:

1. Read a bunch of file into a model
2. Convert the model to another representation.

Ideally you should be able to change (1) and (2) independently.

You can have a class `Model` with a method `Model::Load( <list_of_files> )` that exposes its own data in a common representation (i.e. "Lingua Franca").

Then, you can have [many] classes, one for each new representation (`Representation1`, `Representation2`, and so forth). Each representation class takes a `Model` instance as parameter of its constructor, and in the contructor it will perform the conversion to its own representation.

The format used by `Model` to export its data is common for all the representations, so it's called "Lingua Franca". See the "Lingua Franca Pattern."

```
class Model
{
    public:
        Model( const vector< string >& files )
        {
            // read files and fill data
        }
        boost::ptree Content() const { return data; }
    private:
        boost::ptree data;
};

class RepresentationX
{
    public:
        RepresentationX( const shared_ptr< Model >& model )
        {
            // converts model->Content() in the X format
        }
    private:
        X data;
};

class RepresentationY { ... }; // similar to RepresentationX
```